# Environment variable expansion in persistence.xml (JPA)

Tags: eclipse, jpa, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a Eclipse RCP plugin which uses JPA.
I tried to specify the database path via a variable give to the JVM on runtime.
The property is set correctly but the database is created in a folder named after the variable name (here: ${DBHOME}).

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:${DBHOME};create=true"/>
```

Is there a possibility to fix this?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work but only for JVM variables, not OS/Shell environment variables.  To make your example work, you need to start the JVM with `-DDBHOME=your/path`.

To make this work with shell variables, you need to add `-DDBHOME=$DBHOME` (*nix) or `-DDBHOME=%DBHOME%` (win) to the JVM launch command line.